# Android getBitmap can't find the specified image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

I'm trying to retrieve an image that is stored on my storage after using the Camera's PictureCallback however the getBitmap method can't seem to find the image and it returns the following error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
> file://storage/emulated/0/MyApp/IMG_20150903_154338.jpg

I assure you, the image is available at that location. I checked the location.

> Take the Photo
>
> Get the image through the callback
>
> Display the image in an ImageView

**Image gets saved. Doesn't get displayed.**

Here's my code:

```
captureImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/", "MyApp");

                        if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                            storageDir.mkdirs();//directory created
                        }
                        // get the current timestamp
                        String timest = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                                .format(new Date());
                        //Create your picture file
                        File pictureFile;
                        pictureFile = new File(storageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timest + ".jpg");


                        try {
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                            fos.write(data);
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("MyApp", e.toString());
                        }

                        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);

                        try {
                                Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(CameraActivity.this.getContentResolver() , Uri.parse("file://"+ storageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timest + ".jpg"));
                               
                                imageViewer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewer);
                                imageViewer.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d("MyApp", e.toString());
                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the permission to read from external storage to your androidmanifest.xml ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```